# If I use a static method in PHP to create a connection to a database will I end up with one or many connections?

Tags: php, mysqli, static-methods

I am looking at creating an object that is called upon to pass data to the data store. My implementation uses [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi), but I want to allow other developers to use whatever data store they want.

I was thinking that a static method might be the best answer, but not having any familiarity with them I am unsure if I would be actually creating lots of connections or reusing the same one.

```
<?php
    class RECORDS {

        protected $conn;

        public function __construct() {
            //contect to DB
            $conn = $this::connection();
        }

        public static function &connection(){
            $conn = NULL;
            if($conn==NULL){
                $conn = new mysqli(_DB_HOST_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASS_, _DB_HOST_);
                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" .
                         $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .
                         $mysqli->connect_error);
                }
            }
            return $conn;
        }
        // ... methods that do stuff
    }
```

Have I got the right idea about static methods and will I be reusing the same connection or making new ones?

Comment: Think about singleton.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in this case,         
    "$conn = NULL;
    if($conn==NULL){"
is always going to evaluate to true :)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Singleton? (google it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `protected $conn` field is not a static field, so it is not accessible from a static method (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

You should also use `self::$conn` to access a static field, or `$this->conn` to access object fields. The way you do it, you use a local variable making your `protected $conn` unused. I suppose your code should look like this:

```
<?php
    class RECORDS {

        protected static $conn = null;

        public function __construct() {

            //Connect to database
            self::$conn = $this::connection();
        }

        public static function &connection(){

            if(self::$conn==NULL){
                self::$conn = new mysqli(_DB_HOST_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASS_, _DB_HOST_);
                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" .
                         $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .
                         $mysqli->connect_error);
                }
            }
            return self::$conn;
        }
        // ... methods that do stuff
    }
```